# How do you block players you don't want to play with?

Tags: starcraft-2

The match maker keeps putting me up against the same guy who says glhf then quits. I've faced him about 15 times over the past couple days. Sometimes I get him several times in a row. All I want is a normal ranked game. This is a complete waste of time, and is affecting my ranking in a way that is inaccurate and unfair. Is there any way to avoid this player?

On a side note, why do people do this and is it even in accordance with Blizzard's rules?

Comment: This particular player was previously a diamond league player who has almost all of the achievements unlocked (7k+).

Comment: They do this because they want to make their mmr lower as fast as possibile. They do that for few reasons like farming portraits, achievements, just trolling with low level players or willing to switch race.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the post-game score screen, you can use the drop-down on their name to report them.  If you missed your chance after the game, you can access this screen later via your Match History tab.

Open the drop-down menu, select the "More" option, and then pick "Report Player":

[image: Player Menu]

A new window will pop up where you can select a reason (in this case, "Cheating" is probably most appropriate) and then enter an explanation.

[image: Report Player Window]

I don't know if it is technically violating the rules.  The lead developers have commented in multiple interviews in the past that they don't like players smurfing, so at best it seems to tiptoe the line.  In this case, the player you're talking about is likely losing a bunch of games to be placed in a lower league, so they can rack up a bunch of easy wins to grind out the "Win 1000 matches as X" achievements.

I am not sure if you can be matched with a blocked player.  (In Heroes of the Storm, which uses the same engine and is made by the same dev team, you *can*, but it's also a modified matchmaker.)  But, by reporting the player, you will bring them to Blizzard's attention and they can investigate and respond appropriately.

Comment: In addition to achievements, they may also be trying to rack up easy tournament wins, but I am less experienced with how the tournament system breaks out contestants by MMR.

Comment: Hello, my name is Orc, and I am a former win farmer. *What should you do in your specific case?* Nothing, just wait him out. In several matches he will drop into lower levels of MMR and you will not meet him anymore. Sure, you will get some dirty MMR, but there's nothing you can do but stop playing for now an let others deal with him. *Why do they do that?* There are two possibilities. Either he wants some easy games, or, if he is indeed an achievement hunter, he wants wins. Wins, however, are not gained by roflstomping noobs.

Comment: Playing with normal, but underskilled players is a waste of time. Down below, in the unimaginable darkness of lower Bronze, there is a land of *win traders*. These people maintain a similar MMR and get matched with each other, then take turns to surrender. On average, it is possible to have one hame to last 30 seconds, getting you one win per minute. At maximum efficiency, in a syn-cycle (when you are repeatedly matched to the same person) one can get 2 wins per minute. Normal people there are quickly surrendered to and pushed up, to the land of the normal - ain't nobody got time for this :-)

Comment: I've farmed 500 Terran wins before my sanity started to give in, and I fled back up. Actually, that was long ago, in WoL, and since then there were some announcements about how win trading is undesirable. I am unaware, though, if this land of darkness still exists :-)

Comment: @OrcJMR You're wrong, Orc. The problem is that if everyone did what you did, it would be nearly impossible for some players to find a game. I've heard stories on the forums by new players who have spent two hours in the lobby only to get a couple real games. At the very bottom they still put you up against some of the worse/newest players. What you *should* do instead is add another "achievement hunter" as a friend and challenge them directly. Anything else is abusive, and IMO should be reported.

Comment: @Bizorke sorry, I don't understand which of my statements seems wrong to you. One that normal people do not spend much time among win traders? Of course, it is possible to be stuck there, especially was back then, when the abuse was more widespread. Of course it is abuse. And no, one can't add another hunter as a friend and challenge him. The achievement is for the ladder, and I do sincerely hope one cannot fix a ladder game to always include one's friend.

Comment: You can be matched with a blocked player but you will not be able to see his messages during the game and off the game. People losing like that on purpose want just farm some portraits, or similar, because they can't win most of games against players with close mmr. And no, reporting won't work, it never worked. A player can be banned only if cheating or trash talking (racism etc). And to get that, you need to put some evidence, like replays, screenshot etc on the proper teamliquid.net maphacker thread.

Comment: Update: I find that this isn't such a problem in HotS, which is what I play on, but my girlfriend plays WoL and gets the same guy over and over. She's in gold league.

Comment: @Bizorke The player pool for WoL is very small now so the chances of you getting the same person repeatedly is fairly high.  I haven't seen any further remarks from the devs about changing the matchmaker to avoid blocked players, so it's probably on the to-do list still, but you're unlikely to see it for quite some time.